# dropdown menu like on google

Tags: javascript

how do i create a menu like the one that is on the google homepage for the "more" button and "Settings" button?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here you are :)](http://www.hv-designs.co.uk/tutorials/sliding_menu/sliding_menu.html)

[See the tutorial too](http://www.visual-blast.com/javascript/create-a-vertical-sliding-menu-using-jquery/)

It is nothing more than using [`slideToggle`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) function of jQuery.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here are some jQuery plugins:

- [jQuery iPod-style Drilldown Menu](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ipod_style_drilldown_menu)
- [jQuery UI Selectmenu: An ARIA-Accessible Plugin for Styling a Custom HTML Select Element](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/)